# Can PayPal help calculate CDN tax when Canadian customer pays in US dollars?

Tags: paypal, currency

I have a Canadian client that wants to sell products in USD because the majority of his customers are from the US or are International.  The problem encountered is when a Canadian customer buys in USD they also pay the CDN tax applicable and the client needs to do some sort of conversions at tax time to fix the tax paid.  Does PayPal have a visible conversion in place to account for this so the client doesn't have to research the exchange rate at the time of purchase and make the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Paypal can help you there but the company I work for does have a CA website with USD denomination. All we do is calculate the [proper tax rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxation_in_Canada) (it's easy since it's all province based) and they remit the tax in USD. The Canadians will accept that since they're getting paid.